# thresh.cpp:1676: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function 'cv::adaptiveThreshold'

Tags: python, opencv

Learning this [tutorial at OpenCV of **Adaptive**-Thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html), exact code copied

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv.imread('sudoku.jpg',0)
img = cv.medianBlur(img,5)
ret,th1 = cv.threshold(img,127,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY)
th2 = cv.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,\
            cv.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
th3 = cv.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
            cv.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
titles = ['Original Image', 'Global Thresholding (v = 127)',
            'Adaptive Mean Thresholding', 'Adaptive Gaussian Thresholding']
images = [img, th1, th2, th3]
for i in range(4):
    plt.subplot(2,2,i+1),plt.imshow(images[i],'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

> OpenCV(4.5.2)
> C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-m8us58q4\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\thresh.cpp:1676:
> error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function
> 'cv::adaptiveThreshold'
> File
> "C:\Users\me\Documents\test\AdaptiveThresholding.py", line 8, in
>
> th2 = cv.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,\

opencv-python   4.5.2.52

Python 3.9.5

[image]

Comment: Use `img = cv.imread('sudoku.jpg',cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)` to be compatible with thresholding.

Comment: @fmw42 Works. Although can't accept comment as answer, thank you very much for the info.

Comment: Give credit to `@Tim Roberts` below. His answer to convert to grayscale is just as good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not the EXACT code.  The exact code reads a grayscale PNG.  You have a color JPG.  That's the difference.  adaptive threshhold requires a grayscale image.  So, add:

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Comment: Not only caught the missing, but provide additional instruction. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Covert Your Required image into gray scale bcz adaptive threshold reqires gray scale image
For Example:

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Comment: This is the same solution as in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67512280/2227743). *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*